# Would a member initializer, or assignment in the constructor initialize a member faster?

Tags: c++, performance, member-initialization, ctor-initializer

```
class A {
   public:
   int a;
   A(int x)
   {
      a = x;
   }
};
```

OR

```
class B {
       public:
       int b;
       B(int x):b(x){}
};
```

Which one would initialize the object faster ? Or will same code be generated ultimately for both and the time taken to initialize will remain the same ? Or does it depend on the compiler ?

Comment: For native types, that'd be identical, as they aren't initialized before the body normally.

Comment: Although the two are semantically different, it is unlikely there is a perceptible difference for an `int`. The only way to know for sure is to profile both.

Comment: @juanchopanza Profiling wouldn't be too useful here I guess. And by native types we mean built-in data types ?

Comment: If profiling isn't useful, then there is no difference and this is a non-question.

Comment: The speed of this should not even be a consideration. Doing it correctly should be the only though. Let the compiler worry about making it fast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For POD members, including `int`, they will be the same, because the member won't be constructed twice.

For types with a default constructor, the second will be faster, because the first option is equivalent to:

```
A(B x) : a()
{
   a = x;
}
```

if `a` is a member of type `B` (with a default constructor).

Note that there are situations where you **must** use initializer lists: `const` members, reference members, members of a class-type that don't have a default constructor.

### POD-member:

#### No initializer list:

```
   A(int x)
001F1430  push        ebp  
001F1431  mov         ebp,esp  
001F1433  sub         esp,0CCh  
001F1439  push        ebx  
001F143A  push        esi  
001F143B  push        edi  
001F143C  push        ecx  
001F143D  lea         edi,[ebp-0CCh]  
001F1443  mov         ecx,33h  
001F1448  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
001F144D  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
001F144F  pop         ecx  
001F1450  mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],ecx  
   {
      a = x;
001F1453  mov         eax,dword ptr [this]  
001F1456  mov         ecx,dword ptr [x]  
001F1459  mov         dword ptr [eax],ecx  
   }
```

#### Initializer list:

```
   A(int x) : a(x)
00E71430  push        ebp  
00E71431  mov         ebp,esp  
00E71433  sub         esp,0CCh  
00E71439  push        ebx  
00E7143A  push        esi  
00E7143B  push        edi  
00E7143C  push        ecx  
00E7143D  lea         edi,[ebp-0CCh]  
00E71443  mov         ecx,33h  
00E71448  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
00E7144D  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
00E7144F  pop         ecx  
00E71450  mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],ecx  
00E71453  mov         eax,dword ptr [this]  
00E71456  mov         ecx,dword ptr [x]  
00E71459  mov         dword ptr [eax],ecx
```

i.e. identical, & that's because `a` isn't initialized before entry to the constructor body.

### Non-POD member:

#### No initializer list:

```
00EB1A80  push        ebp  
00EB1A81  mov         ebp,esp  
00EB1A83  sub         esp,0CCh  
00EB1A89  push        ebx  
00EB1A8A  push        esi  
00EB1A8B  push        edi  
00EB1A8C  push        ecx  
00EB1A8D  lea         edi,[ebp-0CCh]  
00EB1A93  mov         ecx,33h  
00EB1A98  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
00EB1A9D  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
00EB1A9F  pop         ecx  
00EB1AA0  mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],ecx  
00EB1AA3  mov         ecx,dword ptr [this]  
00EB1AA6  call        B::B (0EB11D6h)  
   {
       a = b;
   }
00EB1AAB  mov         eax,dword ptr [this]  
00EB1AAE  pop         edi  
00EB1AAF  pop         esi  
00EB1AB0  pop         ebx  
00EB1AB1  add         esp,0CCh  
00EB1AB7  cmp         ebp,esp  
00EB1AB9  call        @ILT+315(__RTC_CheckEsp) (0EB1140h)  
00EB1ABE  mov         esp,ebp  
00EB1AC0  pop         ebp  
00EB1AC1  ret         4
```

#### Initializer List:

```
A(B b) : a(b)
   {
00841650  push        ebp  
00841651  mov         ebp,esp  
00841653  sub         esp,0CCh  
00841659  push        ebx  
0084165A  push        esi  
0084165B  push        edi  
0084165C  push        ecx  
0084165D  lea         edi,[ebp-0CCh]  
00841663  mov         ecx,33h  
00841668  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
0084166D  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
0084166F  pop         ecx  
00841670  mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],ecx  
   }
```

i.e. initializer list option is better.

Comment: Why would there be a difference? Surely the compiler could write the same code for both.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't think the compiler is allowed to elide the default construction in this case.

Comment: @juanchopanza Why not? Is the "as if" principle suspended?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ok, it's *at least* as fast. If there was observable logic in the default constructor, elision would be illegal.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The only way I believe the default construction can be realistically omitted is if both the default constructor and the assignment can be inlined, and the default constructor can then determined to be a dead store (as a result of the assignment). Is that what you meant, or did you have another scenario in mind?

Comment: -1: An assembly listing without any indication of what compiler and compilation settings have been used, and without showing the calling context, is more misleading than useful.